# Modifying a linear function to start flat

Tags: functions, algorithms

**Algorithm:** $y = 0.00001x+0.00001$

Is it possible to convert this linear function to a mathematical algorithm that instead initially starts out flat, constantly being $0.00001$ as long as $0.00001x < 5$?

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of the word "algorithm".

Comment: Yes there are many ways to do that. But you would use an algorithm as a tool to find such a function. It would not be the function itself.

Comment: you just described your "algorithm": 0.00001 if 0.00001x<5 else 0.0001x+0.00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0.00001x<5$

$x<500000$

Therefore, your "algorithm", or equation would be:

$f(x)=0.00001$, when $x<500000$ and $f(x)=0.00001x+0.00001$ when $x\ge500000$

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that there was some mathematical way to include it all in one single formula (as in not including '<' or '>' etc.), but I'm starting to realize this isn't possible, right?

Comment: @PloxCake Yes, this is called a **piecewise function**.

Comment: @PloxCake Please click on the check mark, if you think this is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much I'll be looking into that. Would you know the formula of what I'm trying to accomplish with piecewise?